# <![CDATA["'"]]> returns two result. Some app version print "'", another app version print '. Why?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, jvm

I used  in string.xml.
And used like getText(R.string.something).

Some app version print that string like "'".
And another app version print like '.

Search that keyword 'android', 'CDATA', 'quote', 'getText', 'update'

```xml
<string name="example"><![CDATA["'"]]>example<![CDATA["'"]]></string>
```

```
Timber.d(getText(R.id.example))

// some app print "'"
// another app print '
```

That code returned ' before.
But after version upgrading some libraries related to GTM and glide,
that code returns "'".

---

## **Update**

My best goal is printing ' using `<![CDATA["'"]]>`.

---

## **Update**

Unless can not, want to know why. Because it occured from gradle/library version upgrading side effect.

---

## **Update**

I found why happen this problem.

Problem came from upgrading `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version 3.2.1 to (3.3.0 ~ 3.4.2)
But, if set gradle version to 3.5.0, `<![CDATA["'"]]>` returns ' (what I want)

---

## **Update**

I got answer from google issue tracker assigner
"The output from gradle plugin 3.3.0 ~ 3.4.2 was a bug in aapt2. 3.5.0 restored the correct behavior."

If want to know changes, search 'aapt2 quote' keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it should work fine

"\'"

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But, I want to know case that <![CDATA["'"]]> became not working.

Comment: Actually I not sure , why this happened may be because of grdle.

Comment: Using "\'" without <![CDATA["'"]]> works well. And using \' works well, too. So I will remove <![CDATA[""]> until I know why.

Comment: if it is working, you can mark this as a correct  answer may be another one facing the same issue.

Comment: OK. But I will mark answer after I know what is different gradle plugin version between 3.2.1 and 3.3.0 ~ 3.4.2.

Comment: You can check this link for gradle plugin release https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: Checked this link more than twice..Sorry.. I cannot find any good answer. This is not easy something. So, I submitted to google issue tracker. I'm waiting for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to just show quotes? If so, try using this:

```
<string name="example">\'example\'</string>
```

Use case: `Timber.d(getString(R.string.example));`
CDATA is when you'd like to pack HTML with getText. I don't think you need it here.

Comment: It works. Thanks. But I want to know why it changed not working.

Answer (score 0):

By XML standard:

```
<string name="example">&apos;example&apos;</string>
```

Though probably not *that* easy. (`&quot;` for `"`).

Comment: Works for me, thanks. But I want to use <![CDATA["'"]]>.
Unless cannot use, want to know why.

Comment: `<![CDATA[']]>` could make sense, I have no idea why an apostrophe should be quoted.

Comment: It works well, too.
Not should be quoted but this problem appear from gradle/library upgrading side effect.
So I want to know that did android change CDATA policy? or other change?

Very very thanks for your answer. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the way your are using CDATA sentence, if you still wanna used it, it could be something like

```
<string name="example"><![CDATA[&#039;example&#039;]]></string>
```

Using `&#039;` or `&apos;` for apostrophe symbol.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to know that what affected that code, because it occured from gradle/library version upgrading side effect.